# LEFT JOIN and SUM with GROUP BY - the same result on all rows

Tags: mysql

In the example of the following sqlfiddle I want to get a sales listing of all sellers in a particular country even if one or more sellers do not have sales:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b60247/10/0

```
SELECT ts.name AS seller_name,
 COALESCE(SUM(tsa.sales), 0) AS sales_total
FROM tseller ts
LEFT JOIN tseller_country tsc ON ts.id = tsc.name
LEFT JOIN tsales tsa ON tsc.country = tsa.country
WHERE tsa.country = '1'
GROUP BY ts.name
ORDER BY ts.id
```

However instead of the following result

```
Marie 370
Peter 0
Marge 0
```

I get

```
Marie 370
Peter 370
Marge 370
```

Comment: I would start by renaming your columns: eg `ON ts.id = tsc.name` is confusing.

Comment: How do you know *who* sold *what*? And FWIW, i find the practice of sticking 't' in front of tables really ttedious.

Comment: I don't get it, you have in `tcountry` only id's: 1,2,3,4. and in `tseller_country.country` column, value `6`.

Comment: Sorry. I tried to create a simple example of complex queries.
I want to get a list of sales from all USA sellers (Marie, Peter and Marge).
Marie has three sales. Peter and Marge have no sales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You select the sales solely on the country id. So for every user the same sales are used for the sum as long as they are selling in the given country.

Adding a new rule for the sales join corrects the sum. To see get results with a sum of 0 as well you also need to change the `WHERE` clause to check the `tseller_country` table (sum 0 => no entries in the sales table).

A correct version could be something like this:

```
SELECT ts.name AS seller_name,
SUM(tsa.sales) AS sales_total
FROM tseller ts
LEFT JOIN tseller_country tsc ON ts.id = tsc.name
LEFT JOIN tsales tsa ON tsc.country = tsa.country AND ts.id = tsa.name

WHERE tsc.country = '1'
GROUP BY ts.name
ORDER BY ts.id
```

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x=...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: Thanks Strawberry

Comment: Thanks Jonas Schwabe.